# What guitar accessory is this?

Tags: guitar

[image]

This is a picture of a Jon Gomm guitar. What is this black strip attached to the guitar? Sungha Jung also has a similar thing on his guitar.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely a pickup with a smooth cover. If you look up the manufacturer and model of the guitar, you can find the specific info.

Answer (score 4):

Eric’s answer correctly identifies this object as a pickup, I just thought I’d add some extra info.

This pickup is a magnetic-coil pickup, more commonly found on electric guitars and basses. Pickups for acoustic guitars are more usually Piezo pickups, which react to pressure, rather than the vibration of a string in a magnetic field. For this reason, the kind of pickup pictured will only work on a steel-string acoustic guitar, and not a nylon-string. (I found this out the hard way as a teenager, trying to use my dad’s acoustic guitar pickup to turn my classical guitar into an “electric” - very disappointing results!)

Piezo pickups are internal, so you don’t notice that they’re there; I suppose this makes it more noticeable (and notable) when you see the kind of pickup pictured.

Acoustic guitar magnetic-coil pickups are often removable, designed to fit any steel-string acoustic guitar, effectively turning any purely acoustic guitar into an electro-acoustic. This can be an effective way to mitigate the feedback (and resonance, generally) problems when using a Piezo pickup or especially when using a microphone with an acoustic guitar.

Comment: FWIW magnetic pickups for acoustic guitars work best when used with electric guitar strings or "Zebra" strings with nickel in the windings along with bronze.  The windings on almost all acoustic guitar strings are made from a metal that does not respond well to the magnets in the pickup and shield the steel core from the magnets.

Comment: Many years ago, I used to hook up a set of can headphones to a reel-to-reel recorder and then just put the cans on the acoustic guitar. The headphones work like a microphone. Sound quality will vary.